# How do I create a directory with a file in it, in one step?

Tags: unix, terminal

In the terminal, is there a way to create a directory with a file in it in one step?

Currently I do this in 2 steps:

```
 1. mkdir foo
 2. touch foo/bar.txt
```

Apparently, `touch foo/bar.txt` doesn't work.

Comment: You can always create your own command to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only standard unix tools, the most direct way to create a directory and a file in this directory is

```
mkdir foo && touch foo/bar.txt
```

Unix is built around the philosophy of simple, single-purpose tools with the shell as a glue to combine them. So to create a directory and a file, you instruct a shell to run the directory creation utility then the file creation utility.

I won't swear that there isn't some bizarre way of using a standard tool that lets you do it with a single command. (In fact, there is: unpack an archive — except that you'll need to provide that archive as a file, with predefined owner, date and other metadata, or else use another command to build an archive.) But whatever it is would be convoluted.